# pyspark job execution in yarn cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to understand how spark job work in yarn cluster

I am using below commands to submit job

1. `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster sparksessionexample.py`

After submitting job console shows below console log

```
2020-05-29 20:52:48,668 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-bcd415f0-a22e-46b2-951c-5b6e4385a0c6/__spark_libs__2908230569257238890.zip -> hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1590759398715_0003/__spark_libs__2908230569257238890.zip
2020-05-29 20:53:14,164 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/pythonprojects/Python/src/spark_jobs/sparksessionexample.py -> hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1590759398715_0003/sparksessionexample.py
2020-05-29 20:53:14,610 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/clouderaapp/apache-spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1590759398715_0003/pyspark.zip
2020-05-29 20:53:15,984 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/clouderaapp/apache-spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip -> hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1590759398715_0003/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip
2020-05-29 20:53:18,362 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-bcd415f0-a22e-46b2-951c-5b6e4385a0c6/__spark_conf__7123551182035223076.zip -> hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1590759398715_0003/__spark_conf__.zip
```

I just to understand how yarn execute **sparksessionexample.py** file, i mean whether it create python virtual env on node? as above log shows only uploading lib, confs but what about python client to execute **sparksessionexample.py**?

Can anyone help understand this?

Answer (score 0):

The "Spark client" is used to bootstrap the Spark job execution.

In your case it is the **only** thing that runs on your local machine, because you requested **`cluster` execution mode**:

- the "client" contacts the cluster manager *(here YARN Resource Manager, could be Kubernetes Master, etc.)* to start the Spark driver inside an AppMaster container
- then the driver contacts again the cluster manager to request some containers for the executors
- then the driver runs your Python code and distributes the work to the executors
- finally the driver de-allocates its executors and itself
- at this point the "client" notices that the YARN job has reached success or failure status, and can terminate

In short, the "client" never gets any kind of useful information from the driver running inside the cluster. You must inspect the YARN logs for the container running the driver *(it's the AppMaster, typically number `00001`)*.

---

If you want to see some feedback from the driver, then run your job in **`client` execution mode** -- it means the driver will run in the same JVM as the "client", in your local machine, and spit its logs in your console.

Comment: - then the driver runs your Python code and distributes the work to the executors  -> I am not getting how the driver run Python code in AppMaster as there is no **python client** in AppMaster to execute python code. All libs, confs, spark packages are uploaded but i am not getting how python code execution happens without **python client**

Comment: Have you ever seen a recent Linux OS without a Python 2.x installed? Half of the admin tools depend on it. If you did not install a custom Python run-time, and if you did not set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` env variable to use it, then Spark will use whatever it finds in the PATH. Probably the 2.7 install used by the OS tools.